# Teleport players using rectangular radius

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How would you teleport players using a rectangle radius? When I use the radius command, it selects a grid that's a perfect cube like (`@e[x=1,y=2,z=3,r=6]`) witch will select a 6x6x6 grid around the coordinates `1,2,3` when I need the grid to be something like 6x10x5, so it's not a perfect cube.

Answer (score 2):

Use the dx, dy and dz arguments. They expand the "selection" box starting from the x, y and z arguments.
For example, a 6x10x5 box starting at [1 2 3] would be `@e[x=1,y=2,z=3,dx=6,dy=10,dz=5]`.

Please note however that the x, y and z arguments points to a *corner* of the box. To get it centered, a bit of math will be required.

You can find more info about target selectors on [the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors_In_Java).